# What is the probability of the king's sibling being a male

Tags: probability

The king comes from a family of two children. What is the probability that
the other child is his brother?

Is the probability $1/3$?

Comment: Doesn't this depend on the rules of succession? If the eldest child becomes ruler and the king entered his position by birthright then (barring any death) the king is necessarily the older sibling. Which changed how the odds are computed relative to (say) a patriarchal system with otherwise the same assumptions.

Comment: @YonatanN this is how the problem is stated in my textbook,however, you do make a point

Answer (score 1):

This fun problem is explained in detail in [online MIT probability course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?&v=3mFTpJHHzWA).

The official solution of the problem, assuming probabilities of the sibling being a boy or a girl are $50\%$, is as follows:

Where are 4 equally likely boy-girl outcomes: $BB$, $BG$, $GB$, $GG$;
since we know that one child (king) is a boy, only 3 outcomes remain: $BB$, $BG$, $GB$, also equally likely, and only the outcome $BB$ means that the king's sibling is a boy, so the answer is $1/3$.

But if you think more, the official solution uses additional assumption:
the family predetermined to have 2 children; if you use a different additional assumption, the answer will be different.

Comment: that's if the sibling is a sister

Comment: @DisPxy can you solve it now for a brother?

Comment: no i unfortunately cannot

Answer (score 0):

The human sex ratio is empirically about [1.05 males to 1 female](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_sex_ratio), making the chance of every male birth about 0.512. Note that is a claim about sex at birth, not gender.

In this kingdom, the king is elected, making it (theoretically) irrelevant if this king is the older or younger of the two children. (Empirically, maybe birth order is associated with leadership traits making a person a bit more/less likely to win the election for king; we assume not though.) "King" is a title, and anyone is eligible to run for the office, regardless of their sex or gender. So there is a 0.512 chance the sibling was born male, and 0.488 chance the sibling was born female.

Conservatively, [0.006 of adults are transgender](https://www.pinknews.co.uk/2019/04/02/percentage-us-population-transgender-statistics/) and we assume for now that this is independent of which sex was the birth sex. And regretfully for lack of data, for this calculation we assume that 0.5 of transgender adults identify as the gender traditionally paired with the opposite sex, while the other 0.5 identify as nonbinary.

So under these assumptions there is a $0.512\cdot0.994+0.488\cdot0.006\cdot0.5\approx0.510$ chance that the sibling is a "brother".

Comment: So if the probability was equally likely, then it would be $1/2$?

Comment: You mean if the sex ratio were 1:1? Then the same logic leads to $0.4985$.